# Controlling socket timeouts in external libraries

Tags: python, urllib2

I'm in the process of re-working my personal site and I've run into a bit of a snag that I'm hoping there's a clean workaround for:

I'm using a variety of OS packages to communicate with StackExchange (multiple sites) and Twitter (just for my feed). To speed things up when refreshing my beaker-driven cache, I've multi-threaded my requests using a generic `QueuedCall` class (of my own design).

Now, this works all fine and dandy when providers are up. *However*, it can hang if a provider is down (which I obviously want to avoid). Unfortunately, the libs that I'm using don't expose a method of setting timeouts. The way I see it is that I have one of two options:

1. Kill the threads manually after a specified timeout. *I'd like to avoid this at all costs as it's just bad*.
2. Modify the libraries to accept a timeout argument. I don't particularly want to get into this as it's part of the reason that I'm using 3rd party libs to begin with ;)
3. (Hoping to be able to) set some global property that sets a timeout that `urllib2` will recognize when being used in an external library.

Question: Is there a property somewhere that I can set from my application code to control default timeouts for `urllib2`?

Comment: I'm confused.  The latest urllib2 supports timeouts (http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html) at least for urlopen.

Comment: @CarlF: Yes, but I'm not calling `urlopen` myself, it's being done in an external lib that I'd rather not have to modify.

Comment: Okay.  I get it.  You're using "external libraries" which you suspect (or maybe know) are calling urllib2 under the hood.

Comment: How can you be sure it's urllib2, not urllib, httplib, or socket that's being used to make the connections?  I wonder if @Donkopotamus has the right answer.

Comment: I took a gander at the source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for

```
socket.setdefaulttimeout
```

Comment: Awesome, exactly what i was looking for :P

Comment: That's a rather unexpected solution.  I wouldn't have thought to search through the socket package for url related stuff.  Makes perfect sense now that you said it.